# Use js for validation

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have a form with two buttons, the first buttons confirms the data entered and shows a verification code input, and the other one submits the code and the form, what i want is to put validations at the first button to required fields so he can't confirm unless he has filled all the required fields, how can i do that using js?

```html
<form>
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" required><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" required><br>
    <input type="button" value="Confirm"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Comment: why with JS? what have you tried?

Comment: voting to close, because the question is asking for a tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this

```js
function validate() {
  var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
  
  if(fname==null || fname=="" || lname==null || lname=="") { // Validate the data here
    alert("Please fill all the fields");
  }
  else {
    alert("Data confirmed. Now you can submit.");
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="fname"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lname"><br>
  <input type="button" value="Confirm" onclick="validate()"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" disabled>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/):

```
<form id="UserForm">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" required><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" required><br>
    <input type="button" value="Confirm" onclick="Validate()"><br>
  <input id="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Submit" disabled>
</form>


function Validate() {
   var isValid = $("#UserForm").valid();
   if (isValid)
       $('#submitBtn').prop('disabled', false);
   else
       $('#submitBtn').prop('disabled', true);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You must'n't use JS for validation because you mustn't use client side for this validation. this is evil. Use PHP or a server side to be a litle more secure.

Comment: Using server-side validation is mandatory, but client-side validation could be added and could be a welcome user-friendly enhancement.